Not getting current context in jetpack compose
I am navigating from splash screen to home screen and I want the context of the home screen but I am getting context of the previous screen that is splash screen.
SplashScreen.kt
class SplashActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            ChessTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "splash" ){
                    composable("splash") { Splash(Modifier) }
                    composable("home") { Home() }
                }
                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    delay(2000) // Simulate splash screen delay
                    navController.navigate("home") {
                        popUpTo("splash") { inclusive = true }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

@Composable
fun Splash(modifier: Modifier) {
    Box(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()){
        Text(text = "CHESS",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 50.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
        )
    }
}

HomeScreen.kt
class HomeActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ChessTheme {
                Home()

            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun Home() {
    val modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    ConstraintLayout(modifier.background(
        color = Color.Black
    ).statusBarsPadding()){
        val (menuIcon,notificationIcon) = createRefs()
        (context as HomeActivity).window.statusBarColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.resources,R.color.cream,context.theme) // this line throws error
    }

}

Error
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.chess.SplashActivity cannot be cast to com.example.chess.HomeActivity
at com.example.chess.HomeActivityKt$Home$$inlined$ConstraintLayout$2.invoke(ConstraintLayout.kt:1526)
at com.example.chess.HomeActivityKt$Home$$inlined$ConstraintLayout$2.invoke(ConstraintLayout.kt:89)

I was expecting that LocalContext.current must give the context of home screen which I want to use every where in the screen. Please let me know if there is any solution for this or how I can get context correctly.
Thank You,

First thing first, why are you using multiple activities? Compose is supposed to be a one activity architecture

You created two activities and used navigation to navigate. You must use Intent for that, not navigation. Apart from that cut- paste the Home() composable code after creating a new file named HomeScreen.kt and delete HomeActivity.

@AymanAit Actually it is an old project made is Kotlin which I am trying to reconfigure, but I got your point. Thank you.

@CodeEvo as@robert jamiso  mention you should use intents

The problem is that you are attempting to use a @Composable NavHostController to switch Activities, which it is not capable of doing.  It is only capable of switching @Composables.
Instead, you may want to either:

Use only one activity and continue switching between all of your composables using @Composable NavHostController.  Example here.

Use multiple activities and switch between them using Intents. This is a good method to use if you have permissions or actions that are linked to specific activities.



Thank you @Robert for you helpful answer.

Anytime.  You can also message me directly if you have other compose questions.

The problem is Your are not started HomeActivity, you just navigate home screen from the SplashActivity.
Start the HomeActivity from splash Activity then you will get HomeActivity context inside your home function.
val context = LocalContext.current
context.startActivity(Intent(context, HomeActivity::class.java))


Got it @sasikumar, thanks for your answer

In SplashActivity you created the Splash() composable and navigated to the Home() composable, Which is in the HomeActivity. This means you are not opening a new activity, You just change the composables in the same Activity. That's the reason behind the error.
Code needs SplashActivity context and you are providing HomeActivity context which is not started yet.
As per your code, You are just switching composables in SplashActivity not starting a new HomeActiviy.
I modified the code in the SplashActivity.
SplashActivity
class SplashActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            ChessTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "splash" ){
                    composable("splash") { Splash(Modifier) }
                    composable("home") { Home() }
                }
                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    delay(2000) // Simulate splash screen delay
                    navController.navigate("home") {
                        popUpTo("splash") { inclusive = true }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

Created two new Screen

SplashScreen
HomeScreen

SplashScreen
@Composable
fun Splash(modifier: Modifier) {
    Box(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()){
        Text(text = "CHESS",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 50.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
        )
    }
}

HomeScreen
@Composable
fun Home() {
    val modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    ConstraintLayout(modifier.background(
        color = Color.Black
    ).statusBarsPadding()){
        val (menuIcon,notificationIcon) = createRefs()
        (context as SplashActivity).window.statusBarColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.resources,R.color.cream,context.theme)
    }
}

Now don't need HomeActivity so delete the activity and also remove it from the manifest file.

Yes @PremDanej I got your point, thanks
